# python/slenium, wait till class value in html line changes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

Edit: I figured it out, it would be:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(element_has_css_class((By.ID, 'mail'), "emailbox-input opentip"))
```

---

I am using selenium to create an email verifyer but I have to wait till  a certain element loads, which is the input button, at the beginning its html is:

```
<input id="mail" type="text" onclick="select(this);" data-original-title="Your Temporary Email Address" data-placement="bottom" data-value="Loading" class="emailbox-input opentip disabledText" readonly="">
```

and then the class changes from `class="emailbox-input opentip disabledText"` to `class="emailbox-input opentip"`:

```
<input id="mail" type="text" onclick="select(this);" data-original-title="Your Temporary Email Address" data-placement="bottom" data-value="Loading" class="emailbox-input opentip" readonly="">
```

I want the code to wait for this specific class change, how can I achieve that?

site: https://temp-mail.org/en/

Thanks!

Comment: They have [API](https://rapidapi.com/Privatix/api/temp-mail/).

Comment: Yes but I am trying to do it on selenium to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium sdk for python has `Waits` that can be used for this use case. There is even example with your specific use-case in official documentation:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html. See: *Custom Wait Conditions*